# Why isn't matplotlib plotting all black lines in this grayscale image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, matplotlib

I have the following image (of dimensions 1151x781)

[image]

If I try to plot this image with matplotlib as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread("this_image.png")
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

The result is the following

[image]

This happens if I execute this code by opening a Python shell from the terminal or in a jupyter notebook. The addition of the line `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` before plotting does not seem to help.

I am on macOS Catalina (10.15.4) and I tried this with Python 3.7.1 and Matplotlib 3.0.2.

Do you also experience the same thing? What's the solution?

Please, do not tell me that the solution is to change the size of the figure! Because I know that, by changing the size of the figure, this problem can go away or new black lines are visualized. Of course, I don't want to lose time trying different sizes in order to understand which ones work out and, clearly, this solution is impractical and inflexible.

Comment: Can you share the image file as well?

Comment: @user27286 I am already sharing it in my post above. Just download the first image.

Comment: very interesting

Comment: Try interpolation=“hanning” in the imshow.

Comment: @JodyKlymak That seems to (partially) solve the problem, although the lines don't look black anymore, but gray.

Comment: Yeah that’s how antialiasing works.  If you want black to look black you need to make sure your dpi of your figure is higher than the dpi of the rendered image.  
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_antialiasing.html

Answer (score 0):

Change dpi of figure:

```
img = plt.imread('this_image.png')
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7), dpi=300)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Well, this solution is similar to one that changes the size of the figure, although this one is more predictable.